# Has anyone used "Design Pattern Framework (TM)"?

Tags: design, architecture, design-patterns, code-sample

Has anyone purchased [Design Pattern Framework<sup>TM</sup>](http://www.dofactory.com/Framework/Framework.aspx)?

Are these samples worth investment? Are they practical? What are the pro and cons of the guidelines? Anyone used this in the real-world development?

Comment: I find it kind of hilarious that patterns (or a pattern framework, whatever that is), is being sold off the shelf. I wonder which pattern commmunity has reviewed these in the first place.

Comment: @Vineet, well people spent time and effort to put it up together, which cost money. It is based on the GoF and similar classic books. IMO it is like encyclopedia, some people pay for it, others don't

Comment: you are comparing apples to oranges. Encyclopedias are built on research that is peer reviewed, and so are design patterns; that such efforts cost time and money is immaterial. While $79 might not be a lot, absence of peer-reviews would make you a beta-tester for the patterns.

Comment: This strikes me as the type of thing where you'd spend more time and effort adapting their pre-made pattern to do what you need than just implementing it yourself would have.

Answer (score 4):

I think the name might be confusing things a bit. I bought an earlier version of these a few years ago (for .net 2 or 3 I think). Unless things have changed since then I really wouldn't call it a framework or scaffolding tool.

Basically they've pulled together various design patterns from different sources and for each one provided an example implementation in fairly generic code and another in more idiomatic C# code. A bit like the book [C# Design Patterns](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/059652773X) but a lot more comprehensive.

Personally I found them to be useful learning materials at the time (even though I also have the various pattern books) and well worth the money, but as others have pointed out it's not really going to be the sort of stuff that you can copy and paste into your own projects.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that those 69 implemented GoF patterns are really helpful besides learning about them. Some of them can't even be used without a business-logical context. Not all of them can be written in a generic manner. Moreover, you don't know what to search for in this library when you don't know the pattern for the solution already. And how does it help you then?

**Edit:**
FinnNk is probably right. After taking a closer look at it, I do not think that it's a scaffolding tool or even meant as a framwork, so I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

I used the .NET Framework many years ago and found it to be useful as examples of patterns. But I learn well dinking with code. Others learn better from books and the C# Design Patterns is a good choice for learning the patterns in .NET. Others learn via videos and Pluralsight a course on patterns.

As for the generation, that is the Pro .NET Design Patterns Framework, which contains a generator called Spark. I have not tried it, so I cannot vouch whether it is worth it or not.